# Deployment of SSRS 2012 From SSDT Fails - The specified report server URL could not be found

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have recently installed SQL Server 2012 Developer on my laptop. I created a simple SSRS report using AdventureWorks201. The report builds fine but will not deploy. I get the error "The specified report server URL http:/localhost/Reports_MSSQLSERVER2012 could not be found"

I am able to browse to said URL without issue. I can even upload the report and run it just fine. I am using an administrator account in both cases (on the URL and within SSDT).

Is there some reason why SSDT cannot see the URL I am specifying?

Comment: Is `http:/` a typo in your post or the actual URL you're using?

Comment: Yeah that should be "http://" ... and as I said, I was able to go to that link and upload the RDL just fine.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had created the report under SSDT (2012). Then later when I opened the solution (double-cliked the file) it opened in VS2008 (since I have SQL Server 2008R2 and 2012 installed). 2008 couldn't resolve the URL. I had to open SSDT, then file | open the solution there. Deploy worked just fine.