# BI-Report Project "The specified report server url xxxxx could not be found

Tags: c#, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I am using VS 2015 community and MS Sql server 2014

Trying to learn on how to use Reporting Services with C#  by this article: 
 [Creating a heat map in Reporting Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/92530/)

I have gone through these 
["The specified report server url could not be found" error while deploying to reporting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279871/the-specified-report-server-url-could-not-be-found-error-while-deploying-to-re) 
[Deployment of SSRS 2012 From SSDT Fails - The specified report server URL could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858846/deployment-of-ssrs-2012-from-ssdt-fails-the-specified-report-server-url-could) 
[SSRS Express 2012 - The specified report server URL could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725509/ssrs-express-2012-the-specified-report-server-url-could-not-be-found)

and I still get the same popup "The specified report server url xxxxx could not be found...."

I have tried with: /reportserver. /reports, /reportserver_sqlserverexpress, /reports_sqlserverexpress inside of MS SQL server Reporting Services Config Manager and each time I have stopped and restarted MS sql server as well for each renaming.

Comment: Is this error something you get when deploying a report to the server, or when you are trying to view reports that you have already deployed to the server?

Comment: I am getting the error when compiling it from VS